# Filter only the properties of type function inside a class Typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have this class:

```js
class MyClass {
   foo: string|undefined;
   bar: number|undefined;


   baz(...functions: (keyof this)[]): this {
       console.log(functions);
       return this;
   }
}

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass {
    other() {
        console.log(this.baz('other')) // This is OK!
        console.log(this.baz('foo'))   // This is OK, BUT, I want this to be an error because it's not a function
        console.log(this.baz('test'))  // this is an error, which is OK
        // Type '"test"' is not assignable to type '"other" | "foo" | "bar" | "baz"'.(2345)
        // I'd like to change that list to only have "other" and "baz" as valid options.
    }
}
```

How would I separate the properties from the functions programatically if **I don't know the names of the functions in the classes that might extend `MyClass`**

[Working Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8CwAoauBmA9gQFzQQAuATgJYB2A5gD4CutAJgKZ50dsDc2XNABGYSqVrMAtsI6UW7Lj37ZVOXKIBeACgB0%20vK2DlqBWhFLaA1h3gE80cgAtqEAJQBtALpvSz1%20iCQkLAZhAEIBy6IAT02oa0xqbmbgLqwdCUHOTMlLSOLhBpQgC%202GVY2KCQMAgA8s5yyDXQHAAe5BzstUgoMJjp0ASNlNpugYPBoeYRUTFx-hC6WtoA5MNOcqtu4wD0u9AAKoXQAXUA0gCEQRnQ0%20GR0bHai8tgOquEBNvjuPtHJzO5wANNAAEIAVUOoIAktAAO5gWjkAoBcgEEQcaBI1qUSgESiY4BgZgQLHUcirGC0YbY6AJJJmG4Ze6zJ4LQpvD6dCg-P4HRanGA4uT4yig%20EuYBOIXQC7M4L-Q7wAAOWNWACIeeQNatZTSUTVqPRaGBhJFHBjyKr1RqNnINdBGNANV9Hc6NaJKO6XVpdbptAAmADMABYAKxuBVCf4w1ZsaAgag2S13JxI%20hY5xgFFJiipswgeDQdMANyxdpGjqRCc972rMFLYCTCYIKpMYV0zIqJSAA)

Comment: Even such signature of ```baz``` doesn't work: ```baz<T extends keyof this = keyof this>(...functions: (this[T] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T : never)[]): this```. But, if you change in this signature ```this``` to ```MyOtherClass``` then it will work as expected!

Comment: @НиколайГольцев, doesn't seem to work, I'm getting, for example `Argument of type '"other"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this["other"] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? "other" : never'.(2345)`